# Attribute changes don't propagate via relationships

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship, stackmob

I have a "User" and a "Game" entity which are connected to each other with the "users" and "games" relationships (inverses of each other). When I make a change in a game object that is connected to some user object, the last modification date in the game object is updated. But when I access that game through the user object (in user.games), it still contains the old game object with the old modification date.

I haven't turned on caching yet. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you set the Inverse true while making Core Data Model?

Comment: Yes, the inverse of "games" is "users" and vice versa.